# Getting the last nationality for an employee

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get the list of employees and their nationalities :

```
 select concat([Firstname],[Lastname]) as 'Full name',[C].[Label] as 'Nationality' FROM [Employee] [E]
  left join [AF_AdminFile] [AFA] on E.AdminFileId=AFA.AdminFileId
  left join  [AF_Nationality] [AFN] on AFN.AdminFileId= AFA.AdminFileId
  left join [Country] [C] on AFN.CountryId=C.ID
```

As a result I get the following :

[image]

In this case the employee has changed his nationality , so there is an attribute in the `Employee` table called `UpdatedDate` which is different from NULL (once the nationality is changed)

When I add the date condition in my query as getting the `max(UpdatedDate)` to get the last record for "DavidFELTEN" I get the same result like in the picture above :

```
 select concat([Firstname],[Lastname]),[C].[Label] as 'Nationality' FROM [Employee] [E]
  left join [AF_AdminFile] [AFA] on E.AdminFileId=AFA.AdminFileId
  left join  [AF_Nationality] [AFN] on AFN.AdminFileId= AFA.AdminFileId
  left join [Country] [C] on AFN.CountryId=C.ID
  where [E].UpdatedDate = (select max([Emp].UpdatedDate) from [Employee] [Emp]
                            where [Emp].EmployeeId=[E].EmployeeId)
```

Comment: I'm confused, won't the new row have a value of `NULL`?

Comment: Sample data amd desired output would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT CONCAT([Firstname], [Lastname]) AS full_name,
        [C].[Label] AS Nationality,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY E.EmployeeId ORDER BY UpdateDate DESC) rn
    FROM [Employee] [E]
    LEFT JOIN [AF_AdminFile] [AFA]
        ON E.AdminFileId = AFA.AdminFileId
    LEFT JOIN [AF_Nationality] [AFN]
        ON AFN.AdminFileId = AFA.AdminFileId
    LEFT JOIN [Country] [C]
        ON AFN.CountryId = C.ID
)

SELECT
    full_name,
    Nationality
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```