# How to write SQL query for below information

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having table in below format.

Table name: UserInputHistory

```
UserName    UserEmail       InputText
--------    ---------       ---------
Sriram      sriram@xxx.com  abcd
Arun        Arun@xxx.com    qasas
Ram         Ram@xxx.com     asd
Sriram      sriram@xxx.com  pou
```

I want the query to get output like below.

```
UserName    UserEmail       NoOfInputs
--------    ---------       ----------
Sriram      sriram@xxx.com  2
Arun        Arun@xxx.com    1
Ram         Ram@xxx.com     1
```

In the above table nothing is unique field.I am able to get UserName and count using Groupby. I dont know how to add UserEmail in it.

My query to get UserName and count:

```
select USERNAME, COUNT(*) as NoofInputs from UserInputHistory Group by UserName 
order by UserName
```

Please help me how to write query for above scenario.

Comment: send your query

Comment: I have added my query below, I know only how to get UserName and count.

Comment: Add `UserEmail` to your `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`.

Comment: What's the expected result if you add the row `('Arun', 'arun99@fmail.com', 'sometext')`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the last nationality for an employee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56543775/getting-the-last-nationality-for-an-employee)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add `USEREMAIL` to the `SELECT` and to the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
select
  USERNAME,
  USEREMAIL,
  COUNT(*) as NoofInput
from UserInputHistory
group by USERNAME, USEREMAIL
order by USERNAME, USEREMAIL
```

Adding USEREMAIL to the `ORDER BY` is optional but might be nice to have in case there are multiple users with the same name but different emails (not sure if that is a possibility in your scenario)

Answer (score 2):

Just like this

```
select USERNAME, UserEmail, COUNT(*) as NoofInputs from UserInputHistory Group by UserName, UserEmail        
order by UserName
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below query:

```
select USERNAME,UserEmail, COUNT(*) as NoofInputs from UserInputHistory Group by UserName ,UserEmail
order by UserName
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add all non-aggregate columns to group by:

```
select USERNAME, UserEmail, COUNT(*) as NoofInputs 
from UserInputHistory 
Group by UserName, UserEmail 
order by UserName
```

Answer (score 1):

The columns you are looking for are UserName, UserEmail, and the count of the number of rows for that user.

The following query will work:

SELECT UserName, UserEmail, count(*) as NoOfInputs
FROM UserInputHistory
group by UserName, UserEmail
order by NoOfInputs desc, UserName asc

You need to group by all non-aggregated fields that are being selected.
I've also ordered it by the number of inputs (descending), followed by the Username (ascending).

Answer (score 1):

Please run below query for desired output.

```
SELECT USERNAME
    ,USEREMAIL
    ,COUNT(*) AS NoofInput
FROM UserInputHistory
GROUP BY USERNAME
    ,USEREMAIL
ORDER BY USERNAME
    ,USEREMAIL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select USERNAME, COUNT(*) as NoofInputs
from UserInputHistory 
group by UserName, UserEmail
order by UserName
```

Answer (score 1):

```
No need of using order by username.
If you are using order by 
it will sort your data according to the username.
```

**Simply use this :**

```
select USERNAME, UserEmail, COUNT(*) as NoofInputs from UserInputHistory Group by UserName, UserEmail
```